# Directory template for Wordpress - Free or Paid

Tags: wordpress, theme, directory, template

I'm looking for a wordpress template to create a website's directory. Anyone know?

The template can be paid or free.

Comment: Are you talking about a site contains links. people can read revies and vote. or something else? can you give any link or example for reference..

Answer (score 1):

A WordPress [archive index](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index) should do the trick - you might also consider the [Google sitemap](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) plugin.